# Wordpress do_shortcode with $atts['shortcode'] inside

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I just faced the problem while trying to display my shortcode, hope anybody can show me a solution:

My goal: I need a textfield in Visual Composer, so I can add a unique shortcode for each of my payment buttons.

Here is the textfield I've created:

```
array(
        'type'          => 'textfield',
        'heading'       => esc_html__('Shortcode', 'softing'),
        'param_name'    => 'shortcode',
        'edit_field_class' => 'vc_col-sm-4',
        ),
```

Here is the shortcode I will insert into it: *[purchase_link id="3839" text="Add To Cart" style="button" color="orange"]*

Now I'm trying to display the shortcode with:

```
$out .= '<div class="pricing-box-shortcode">'.'<div class="#pricing-box-shortcode">'.do_shortcode($atts['shortcode']).'</div>'.'</div>';
```

Here is the result & my actual problem:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yd8gJ.png)

I noticed that if I don't use *$atts['shortcode']* but instead just paste my shortcode - it works.

```
do_shortcode([purchase_link id="3839" text="Add To Cart" style="button" color="orange"])
```

Any solution or a clue would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add shortcode for button you may also use below code as it also working as shortcode and you can show button as well

```
function button_shortcode( $atts ) {
        return "<input type='button' id='3839' class='button_class_name' name='button_name' value='yes'>";
    }
    add_shortcode( "purchase_link", "button_shortcode" );
```

You can use above shortcode in page as:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[purchase_link]'); ?>
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do:
I have 3 pricing boxes (plans) with their own prices.
See screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/athMI12.png

Now I'm trying to add shortcodes for each of them via textfields I've created in VC. (shortcodes are unique for each button).
See screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/mRSk6xK.png

As a result, it just outputs broken text without displaying the shortcode. See screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/XWQQoPJ.png